# How to get a value in another table in R?

Tags: r, tibble

My problem is probably simple for many of you. I have a tibble that contains a list of categories with values next to them related to that category.
I want to create a dataset from these values. For this I create a new tibble. In a column I draw one of the categories at random (function sample, replace =T). In the second column I want to add noise to the characteristic value of this category.
My problem is to find out how to refer to the cell that is relative to this particular category in another table.

Here is an exemple :

```
library(tidyverse)

carac <- tibble(
  class = c("raptor","valor","defender"),
  weight = c(123,125,596)
)

test <- tibble(
  serie = sample(carac$class,100, replace=T),
  weight = weight_of_this_class*rnorm(1,mean=1, sd=0.2)
    )
```

I don't know what to use instead of "weight_of_this_class" ? I tried carac[class], but obviously doesn't work :/

What i want i a table like that :

```
# A tibble: 100 x 2
   serie    weight
   <chr>     <dbl>
 1 raptor     142.5
 2 defender   660.3
 3 raptor     129.6
 4 valor      132.1
 5 defender   822.3
 6 defender   611.5
 7 valor      117.4
 8 raptor     112.7
 9 valor      150.6
10 defender   712.6
# ... with 90 more rows
```

(manually calculated data for the example of what i want, it's just "123*rnorm(1,mean=1, sd=0.2)" for the raptor, for example.)

Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
test <- tibble(
            serie = sample(carac$class,100, replace=T),
            weight = sapply(serie, 
                     function(x){carac[carac$class==x, 2][[1]]})
                     *rnorm(1,mean=1, sd=0.2)
)
```

Another approach:

```
serie = data.frame(class = sample(carac$class,100, replace=T))
test = as_tibble(merge(serie, carac, by = "class", all.x = TRUE))
test$weight = test$weight * rnorm(1,mean=1, sd=0.2)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, since `series` is not defined.

Comment: @slamballais Sorry, it's a typo. Corrected it.

Comment: This is an elegant solution (the "sapply" one), and perfectly what i want. Only one line of code, too ! I have to do that for 20 variables, and call the values (like weight for class) in 3 different tables in my real database. Juste move one ")" to include the rnorm in each iteration.

Comment: Just a question : imagine you have a column named "sd" in my first tibble, like carac$sd in my example. In fact, i have a different value for the sd in each category, and i want use this value in the rnorm in place of the fixed "0.2". How can i do that ?

Comment: @Aytan (assuming the third column is "sd")
weight = sapply(serie, 
             function(x){carac[carac$class==x, 2][[1]]
             *rnorm(1,mean=1, sd=carac[carac$class==x, 3][[1]])})

Answer (score 1):

As you are using the `tidyverse` you can just use `slice_sample`...

```
test <- carac %>% 
  slice_sample(n = 100, replace = TRUE) %>%    #sample from the rows of carac
  mutate(weight = weight * rnorm(100, mean = 1, sd = 0.2)) #add noise
```

Comment: It works, but i think i can't do that if i want to refere to multiples tables ?

Comment: @Aytan It should be straightforward to simply `bind_rows` of several tables (either before or after sampling, depending on what you are trying to do)

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to simply sample beforehand, store it in `s`, and then subset `carac$class` and `carac$weight` with `s`:

```r
n <- 100
s <- sample(nrow(carac), n, r = T)
test <- tibble(
  serie = carac$class[s],
  weight = carac$weight[s] * rnorm(n, mean = 1, sd = 0.2)
)
```

Comment: It's a good answer, but i don't want to have multiples isolated values declared in my code (like "s", "n" ...). I have to do that for multiples tables and column, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `match` to get the corresponding `weight` of `serie` value selected.

```
tibble::tibble(
  serie = sample(carac$class,100, replace=TRUE),
  weight = carac$weight[match(serie, carac$class)]*rnorm(1,mean=1, sd=0.2)
)
```

Comment: OP seems to want varying weights with each sample, see their expected output. That's also why I define `n` beforehand, so that you can call `rnorm(n)`.

Comment: Yes, it report the same value for each iteration of each category, this is not really what i want, but i appreciate the concise form, and in the absolute it's the answer of the first part of my question